# PHP | Accessing an Object within an Object

Tags: php, json, api, object

Hi I am very new to using API's with PHP. This is my first attempt. So far I have got the data being returned in a JSON format. I have the `json_decoded()` it and the `var_dump()` is returning what I can only work out as an object within an object. My PHP inexperience might be showing here.

Below is the code I am using which is successfully retrieving data.

```
    $url = 'https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/elderofaegis?api_key=RemovedForSO';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $result = json_decode($output);
    var_dump($result);
```

Below is what the `var_dump()` is returning

```
object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'elderofaegis' => 
     object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'id' => int 38186794
      public 'name' => string 'ElderOfAegis' (length=12)
      public 'profileIconId' => int 785
      public 'summonerLevel' => int 30
      public 'revisionDate' => float 1427933098000
```

Does anyone know how I could access the object by its name. By this i mean the sections contained within the quotes for example if i want to echo the name i want something along the lines of (Pseudo Below).

```
echo $result->object['name'];
```

The above example is Pseudo Because I can't figure it out.
For anyone wondering this is the League Of Legends API

Thanks.

Comment: So whats the problem are you not able to access it or what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$result->elderofaegis->name;
```

Comment: This does work but how would the middle section 'elderofaegis' be populated?
`$result->elderofaegis->name;`
Because I only get that after the request, say iw as to request the same statement by id

Comment: Structure is defined by api response. You need to write some sort of transformer to translate response to your desire object.

Answer (score 0):

you can add `true` as the second parameter to `json_decode($json, true)` this will transform the entire object to an array which will make it more accessible reference this

[json-decode.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: I see this now returns as an array